# Как полностью развернуть принт очень длинного текста?

Tags: python

Открываю текстовый документ с одной огромной строкой и после его прочтения при принте выдает одну огромную строку, которую можно листать ползунком. Как ее полностью развернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
file = open("24-03.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
print(text)
```

Comment: если вам только посмотреть в системе, тожно использовать команду - less file.txt, также в visual code наверняка есть настройки на перевод строки для подобных случаев.

Answer (score 1):

"Развернуть", как вы выразились её не получится в прямом смысле слова, но вывести построчно можно.

```
file = open("24-03.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
for i in range(0, len(text), 50):
    print(text[i:i+50])
```

P.S. Никогда не используйте [зарезервированные имена](https://myrobot.ru/python/02_keywords.php#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20(%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5)%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8,False%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20None.) как названия переменных.